# What is the mass of a human retina?

Tags: eyes, literature, human-eye

I'm struggling to find a reference for the mass or density of a human (monkey or rabbit would also work) retina.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research and I found this site : https://www.covance.com/content/dam/covance/assetLibrary/posters/StrubleEVER14.pdf

It has the weight for ocular tissues for different kinds of animals ( rabbit , human  etc. ).

I also found that the area of a retina is 1094 mm² and the thickness is 0,12 mm , so if you can find the density you can find the mass.

(found on this site https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/facts.html#sensory )

Comment: Are you sure that the referenced value of 2500 mm^2 is not the *surface* area? Because there is no way that the retina is 5 cm x 5 cm.

Comment: I'm sorry . I did some more research and you are right. The actual area of the retina that i found is  1,094 mm^2 (Link that i used https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11556/ )